# Failure to update schema when launching weceem

Tags: hibernate, weceem

I am trying to get the weceem CMS system running on an ubuntu 14.04 server.

I have a tomcat7 installation running and showing its manager app.

I downloaded weceem 1.3 and unpacked the war in the webapps/weceem directory.

I am running mariadb (version 5.5.41-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) and created the weceem database, as well as the weceem user with appropriate permissions.

I have a /etc/tomcat7/weceem.properties file which contains the credentials and it appears weceem uses these to access the database.

When weceem launches, catalina.out contains the following error:

```
2015-02-28 17:34:15,004 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:183)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:92)
```

It appears hibernate is not able to perform the schema update on the database.

Suggestions on what may be wrong here?

Is it possible this as to do with the particular database engine being used? (This version of MariaDB uses InnoDB by default).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I didn't specify **dataSource.dialect** in *weceem.properties*. When I tried for MariaDB (your_version but on Win) the following connection 
    
    `dataSource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    dataSource.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    dataSource.username=root
    dataSource.password=root
    dataSource.dbCreate=update
    dataSource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/weceemmariadb`

the application starts successfully.